# Adicionar elementos com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como adiciono elementos acima e abaixo de vários paragráfos com jquery.
Digamos, tenho que pegar o terceiro parágrafo e adicionar uma `<div>` e finalizo a `</div>` no penúltimo parágrafo.

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
```

O resultado seria este:

```
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <div>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <p>7</p>
```

Eu tentei com `after` e `before`, mas o navegador fecha as tags.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui realizar o que desejava:

```
$("p").slice( 2, 5 ).wrapAll( '<div></div>' );
```